# AVL tree: difference between leaves' depths?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, avl-tree

A question from a test:

Let `T` be an AVL tree, and `x,y` are two leaves in the tree (`x != y`). What's the maximum value of `depth(x) - depth(y)`?

```
A. 0
B. 1
C. 2
D. None of the above
```

The correct (?) answer is D. Can someone explain why it isn't B, as one of the AVL properties is that `height(a.left) - height(a.right) <= 1` for every node `a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To explain in a general way takes more time than showing a counterexample. So, consider the following Fibonacci tree of 8th order, which is an AVL tree:

[image]

Taking depth as the number of edges from root to the nodes, leaf 0 has depth 7 while leaf 52 has depth 4. The difference is 3. With others and larger AVL trees, the difference could be larger.

Remember that what does a tree AVL is that the differences between heights of left and right subtrees for every each node are less or equal to 1. The depth is another thing.

To be honest, it is a tricky question.

Comment: It seems weird for me as the tree must remain balanced in order for the operations to be O(logn). no?

Comment: It is. But the algorithms work because is AVL. A Fibonacci tree is a critic AVL in the sense that if you remove any leaf other than 0, then the tree stops being AVL. It is a kind of border tree and the concept is used to demonstrate the maximum height of an AVL tree. Its definition is recursive. Fib(0) = 0 and Fib(1) = 1. Next Fib(i) = <Fib(i - 1), i + 1 number of Fibonacci, Fib(i - 2) + i number of fibonacci>. The height of the left tree is i - 1 and the height of the right is i - 2 for every non-leaf node. So, the heights difference always is -1 and the tree is AVL. You could review Knuth V1

Answer (score 3):

An AVL tree guarantees that "worst" case look up time is O(log(n)). And it guarantees that at most the height difference of any two subtree's is at most 1. But this does not guarantee that the height difference between lowest and highest node of an entire tree will be 1. In a large tree it is possible to get large height differences for the tree as a whole.

The key to understanding AVL tree's is understanding its definition of a "subtree".  For any given node there are 2 subtree's sometimes called the left and right subtrees. The height difference between those two subtrees is at most 1. Now imagine both those subtrees can be attached to a node and become one subtree in an even larger tree. This new subtree, call it the left subtree of a node will have at most a height difference of 1 with the right subtree on the same node. But this also means that the maximum height difference between any 2 leaves in this entire tree will be 2. This process can be repeated and AVL tree's can have large height difference's between any to leaves, but still maintain it's big O running times.